# tratamento de erro, rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Esse erro acontece quando o usuario nao seleciona a opcão do campo select.
O erro ate seria tratado se nao tivesse o collect:

```
NoMethodError in Subdisciplinas#create
Showing _form.html.erb where line #18 raised:

undefined method `collect' for nil:NilClass

    <%= f.select :disciplina_id, 
        options_for_select(
          @disciplinas.collect { |disciplina| [disciplina.nome.titleize, disciplina.id] }, @subdisciplina.disciplina_id), {prompt: 'Selecionar disciplina'}, { id: 'disciplinas_select' } %>


      </div>
```

Controller onde acredito que o erro deveria ser tratado:

```
def create
    @subdisciplina = Subdisciplina.new(subdisciplina_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @subdisciplina.save
        format.html { redirect_to @subdisciplina, notice: 'Subdisciplina was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @subdisciplina }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @subdisciplina.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não está carregando o `@disciplinas` no `create`. Como dá algum erro de validação ele tenta renderizar novamente as `view`, mas `@disciplinas` está vazio.

Carregue ele igual a você deve ter feito na `action` `new`